# issues while using ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod to invoke private method

Tags: junit, mockito, junit5, spring-boot-test

I am writing a happy path unit test for `method_a` which calling a private method `method_b`.
The service is based on springboot framework and java8.
Junit5 and Mockito are used for unit test.

Following are the basic code structure, sorry can't show the original code.

```
public class SomeClass {

public boolean method_a(obj obj_data) {
    ...

    Optional<String> str;
    str = method_b(str_1);
    
    if(!str.isPresent()) {
        return false;
    }

    ...

    return true;
}

private Optional<String> method_b(String str) {
    ...
    try {
        ...
        return Optional.of(thirdPartCtrl.method_c(val_1));
    }
    cathch (Exception exception) {
        ...
        return Optional.empty();
    }
}
}
```

Following are the unit test code:
approach_1:

```
@Test
void test method_a() {
...
when(ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(SomeClassMock,"method_b", "str_input")).thenReturn(Optional.of("validData"));

...
assertTrue(SomeClass.method_a(val));
}
```

approach_2:

```
@Test
void test method_a() {

...
doReturn(Optional.of("validData")).when(ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(SomeClassMock,"method_b", "str_input"));
...
assertTrue(SomeClass.method_a(val));
}
```

I noticed that when I run the unit test, `java.lang.NullPointerException` was always generated from line `return Optional.of(thirdPartCtrl.method_c(val_1));` in the private method `method_b`

Current issue is:
If I do not use `ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod` to invoke the private `method_b`, `SomeClass.method_a(val)` will always return false.

By using

```
when(ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(SomeClassMock,"method_b", "str_input")).thenReturn(Optional.of("validData"));
```

I will get error

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.WrongTypeOfReturnValue: 
Optional cannot be returned by convert()
convert() should return NotificationRequestDetails

***

If you're unsure why you're getting above error read on.
Due to the nature of the syntax above problem might occur because:
1. This exception *might* occur in wrongly written multi-threaded tests.
   Please refer to Mockito FAQ on limitations of concurrency testing.
2. A spy is stubbed using when(spy.foo()).then() syntax. It is safer to stub spies - 
   - with doReturn|Throw() family of methods. More in javadocs for Mockito.spy() method.
```

If I use

```
doReturn(Optional.of("validData")).when(ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod(SomeClassMock,"method_b", "str_input"));
```

will get error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.NotAMockException: 
Argument passed to when() is not a mock!
Example of correct stubbing:
    doThrow(new RuntimeException()).when(mock).someMethod();
```

What did I do wrong with `ReflectionTestUtils.invokeMethod`?
Is there a better way to mock the private method to return a valid value?
Any suggestion are appreciated! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

How to test private method? How to mock a private method? These are different concepts. You seem to mix them together.

If you want to test private method, you'd call private method **directly** from your test case by using ReflectionTestUtils.

https://roytuts.com/how-to-test-private-methods-using-junit-5/

When you test public method a, which would call private method b, the private method b would be called automatically assuming both methods are in same Class A. So you might want to mock the return of private method. This is impossible in Mockito.

Workaround 1:
Changing private access modifier to default
Partially mock testing object by using spy

https://lkrnac.net/blog/2014/01/mock-private-method/#mock-private-method

Workaround 2:
Refactor private method b to public method in Class B

Also we can't mock private method for Injectmock object. You might need to go with workaround 2
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565726/how-to-mock-a-private-method-under-a-injectmocks-annotated-class-in-java#:~:text=TLDR%3B%20you%20cannot%20use%20InjectMocks,logic%20in%20your%20java%20project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64565726/how-to-mock-a-private-method-under-a-injectmocks-annotated-class-in-java#:%7E:text=TLDR%3B%20you%20cannot%20use%20InjectMocks,logic%20in%20your%20java%20project).